# Zabbix:Calculated items from calculated items

Tags: zabbix

I have a problem creating calculated items from another ones.

For example i have an item inside a host that is a calculated item from 2 different existenting SNMP items.

When I create in a different host a different calculated item that try to calculate the same operation using 2 calculated items in a different host I obtain a not supported tag with this message:

> Cannot evaluate function [avg(0)]: item [SMS_Reference:last("Host1:CalculatedItem"] not found

My formula:

```
last("Host_1:Calculated_item_in_Host_1")
```

In fact `Host_1:Calculated_item_in_Host_1` is another calculated item inside another host and is working perfectly.

Anyone knows how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please show the full expression that you are trying to use in the problematic item? Currently, it seems that there is something wrong with the syntax that you are using, because the error message refers to item `SMS_Reference:last("Host1:CalculatedItem"`, which is not a valid item reference.

Comment: At last it was a syntax problem, but not in relation with the syntax problem showed inside Zabbix debugger, totaly different. Thank you for your help.